# Copy value from table rows to clipboard (PHP, SQL and JS)

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, copy

**There was a different question and somebody marked it as a duplicate although it was not.**

I have created a PHP file that shows all the images I have saved in a database (mySQL in PHPmyadmin):
[image]

The idea is that the image link ($onoma) gets copied in the clipboard, when I click the button. So, I have created an invisible `<p>` and I am getting the copy-value from there.

It works fine in a single html file (static rows), but in my PHP file it copied all the image links from each row and it concatenates them.

I have pasted the code below (with the "Image Preview" and "Copy to Clipboard" columns only) as I cannot use a snippet for PHP :

```
    <?php       
    $co=0;
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
    $onoma=$row['filename'];

    $res=mysql_query($sql);
    $count=mysql_num_rows($res);
    $co++;

    ?>
            <script>
            function copyToClipboard(element) {
              var $temp = $('<input>');
              $('body').append($temp);
              $temp.val($(element).text()).select();
              var gamo = <?php echo json_encode("copy$co"); ?>;
              document.execCommand($gamo);
              $temp.remove();
            </script>   
    <?php 
            echo "
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <img src=\"$onoma\" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <p style=\"visibility: hidden;\" class=\"copy$co\">$onoma</p>
                    <div id=\"button\" onclick=\"copyToClipboard('copy$co')\">COPY</div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        "; 
    }
    mysql_close();          
?>
```

And it does not copy anything. In the console I am getting this error :[image]

After implementing this script exactly :[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

chnage `document.execCommand($gamo);` to `document.execCommand(gamo);`

Comment: That did not change anything I am afraid.

Comment: I accidentally downvoted the comment. Edit it so I can take it back. I have pasted the answer below. I made a stupid mistake with the command.

Answer (score 0):

The command cannot be dynamic. I accidentally made the command dynamic because it has the same name with the class. The line : `document.execCommand("copy$co");` was wrong. The correction is shown below:

```
        function copyToClipboard<?php echo "$co";?>(element<?php echo "$co";?>) {
            var $temp = $("<input>");
           $("body").append($temp);
           $temp.val($(element<?php echo "$co";?>).text()).select();
           document.execCommand("copy");
           $temp.remove();
        }
```